# when I SetLastWriteTime for a directory , an exception happens as " the document is being processed by another process "

Tags: c#

First, I delete a file. Then,  I I try to modify the file's parent directory's last write time.
Last, I got an exception: "The process cannot access the file '（parent path）' because it is being used by another process".

```
string name = file.FullName;

Console.WriteLine(name);

string dir = file.DirectoryName;

DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime("2007-8-1");

File.Delete(name);

try
{
    Directory.SetLastWriteTime(dir, dt);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
}
```

I want to delete a file, and modify the directory's lastwritetime. THANKS A LOT!

Thank for Adam Jachocki's suggest , I fix the code :

```
string dir = fis[0].DirectoryName; ;
 DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime("2007-8-1");
 foreach (FileInfo fi in fis)
  {
      string name = fi.FullName;

        Console.WriteLine(name);

        File.Delete(name);

  }

   Directory.SetLastWriteTime(dir, dt);
```

But the exception still happens.

Comment: What is the type of `file`?

Comment: text file ， suffix is txt

Comment: I mean, what is the declared type of the `file` object in your code?

Comment: FileInfo files =  DirectoryInfo.GetFiles("ab12.txt" ) ; foreach (FileInfo file in files)...

Comment: There's really not much you can do if another process has claimed a handle on a directory/file. But if this directory and/or files are created and managed by your own program, then you're probably not disposing your objects properly.

Comment: That code can't be what you're actually using because `Directory.SetLastWriteTime(dir, dt);` won't compile if `dir` is a `DirectoryInfo`. `SetLastWriteTime()` wants a string as its first argument.

Comment: In fact , the text file is created by administrator , and I run this binary code using administrator too

Comment: @MatthewWatson  Sorry !  string dir = file.DirectoryName;

Comment: I hate this error message. More often than not, *your* process is the "other" process. You've got some other handle to the directory open when you're trying to change it. Find the other object(s) which are still alive, undisposed, and referencing the directory itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this outside the loop.

Enumerator does not returns all files. It rather returns next file every loop. So it may use the directory all the time, thus you get the exception. You should do:

```
foreach(var file in DirectoryInfo.GetFiles(...))
{
   File.Delete(...);
}

Directory.SetLastWriteTime(...); //<-- outside the loop
```

Comment: Thanks! I try your suggest ,and the exception is still happens .

Comment: This is because inside the loop you should ONLY DELETE files. And/or do some other work but with FILES. Work with directory should be done outsize the loop. Just move dir and dt outside the file. If you do the work with multiple dirs (your code doesn't show this), you should add all the directories into a List and then after work is done, you can change the directories properties.

Comment: That's stupid, but are you sure that you don't have for example Explorer or Total Commander opened on this folder?

Comment: You're right ! I closed Explorer which is on drive F:/ , and it works .

Comment: But I still want a solution which can work well when the Explorer is on the root of a drive!

Comment: I think this should work when you're not inside the directory.